# Why does a Javascript function call not contain '()' after the name of the function?

Tags: javascript, syntax, dom-events

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('clickMe').onclick = runTheExample;
}

function runTheExample() {
  alert('running the example');
}
```

This is a simple event handler for the `onclick` event for an html input button with id = clickMe.

In line 2, why is the call to function `runTheExample` not immediately followed by `()`? I thought that to call a function you must pass it any variables/objects it expects in an open/close parenthesis, and if the function isn't expecting anything, you must still include the open and close parenthesis like `runTheExample()`.

Comment: It's very simple: That isn't a _call_ to the function.

Comment: Think of `()` as a way to call a function. If you set the `onclick` to `runTheExample()`, it will call `runTheExample()` immediately and try to run the return of that function (`undefined`/`true`/whatever you set it at).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('clickMe').onclick = runTheExample;
```

The intention here is not to call *runTheExample()* but to assign **the reference to the function runTheExample** to the *onclick* event.

Internally, when the *onclick* event is fired, Javascript is able to call the function *runTheExample* through the reference you provided on the code above.

### Snippet

```
var myFunction = function() { return 42; };

// Assigning the reference
myObject.callback = myFunction;

myObject.callback(); // Has the same effect as calling myFunction();

// Assigning by calling the function
myObject.callback = myFunction();

myObject.callback;   // Returns 42
myObject.callback(); // Exception! Cannot call "42();"
```

That's not Javascript-specific. Passing functions by reference is available in many languages.

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful, particularly the snippet. Thank you.

Comment: Note also that `myObject.callback = myFunction();` is assigned **immediately** and not when you access `.callback`.

Answer (score 5):

You use the parenthesis only to *invoke* (call) a function. When you're assigning it to `onclick`, you're merely passing it by reference.

To better understand this, think about the other method of declaring a function:

```
var runTheExample = function () {
  alert('running the example');
}
```

Regardless of what method you use, `runTheExample` will contain a reference to the function (there are some differences, like the function reference not being available before assignment, but that's a different story).

Answer (score 3):

It's not calling it, but rather setting the property `onclick`. When a call is made to `onclick()`, it will then run the function you've defined. Note however that the context of `this` will be the object that calls it (`document.getElementById('clickMe')`).

Answer (score 3):

Functions are objects in javascript.  That line sets the onclick property of the click me element to the runTheExample function, it doesn't call that function right then.

```
var a =runTheExample; //sets a to runTheExample
a(); //runs the runTheExample function
```

So when the function name is referenced without the () it is referring to the function object, when you add the () it is a call to the function, and the function executes.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the runTheExample function is being treated as a variable and being assigned to the onclick event handler.  You use () after a function name to call a function.  If you added them here, what would happen is that runTheExample() would be called once during load, showing an alert, and then a null value would be assigned to the onclick handler.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the function here. You're setting the function as an event handler, and the function is not actually called called until the event is fired. What you've written references the function; that's a different notion than actually calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Because it binds `runTheExample` to `onclick` event.
When you add `()` it triggers the function.